# Scrolling sideways in a div

Tags: jquery, html, ios, ipad, jquery-mobile

Is there any script or jquery plug in that would allow a user to scroll from left or right inside of div that acts as a menu?

The entire page would be static but you could swipe left or right to choose a different page. The end result would be viewed on an ipad. Similar to the cover flow feature in any ios device.

Comment: swipe? So this is for touch devices? Have you seen this pattern before? Could you link to an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Lol, seems like i misunderstood the question. You can create your own touchbased slider using jQuery mobile or [swipe.js](http://swipejs.com/). Also i found a touchbased slider plugin here: http://www.photoswipe.com/

If you want to do your custom slider, examine jsFiddle over there.

You can create a mask area and place elements in it than by using [mousewheel](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos) plugin you can calculate wheel's velocity speed. You can use this value for animating mask area:

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/332/)

```
$('.mask').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
    var dir = delta > 0 ? 'up' : 'down', 
    vel = Math.abs(delta);//mousewheel's velocity value

    var cur = parseInt($('.imgHolder').css('left'));

    if( dir === 'up' && cur <= 0 ) {
        $('.imgHolder').css({'left':'+='+ vel*5 +'px'});
    }
    else if ( dir === 'down' && cur > -1100 ){
        $('.imgHolder').css({'left':'-='+ vel*5 +'px'});
    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this:

```
div
{
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: op asks "acts as a menu" overflow will just scroll through content.

Comment: Couldn't the content in the div be a menu?  I guess a working example would help a lot.

Comment: yeah thats not what I was thinking of, a good way to think of it is something similar to the album view from any ios device, you can slide it choose from what every element is there.

Comment: Wow, people sure are down-vote happy on this site.  What's the point if you don't comment on the reason for the down-vote?  How does that help the person giving the answer?

Comment: So are you looking for touch-based or mouse-based functionality?

Comment: for touch-based, the end result will be viewed on ipad

Comment: OK, thanks.  You'll want to add this info to your question.  Give as much info as possible.  Also make sure you use all the relevant tags (ios, ipad, etc).

Comment: alright, but do you know of anything that could achieve this? oh and by the way, I didnt give the down-vote. I actually just noticed that you could do that after you pointed it out

Comment: I know.  It's usually not the person asking the question that down-votes.  Anyway, unfortunately I don't know what is used for this functionality.

Comment: @N1tr0 your comment about "What's the point..." I did comment. And I believe my downvote was completely valid.  You in no way answered the asker. Granted, he didn't give a LOT of detail, however he was quite clear that he wanted a menu like appearance with some jQuery plugin, that was display on [ios].   I'd spend a little less time worrying about your reputation, than focusing on answering the askers questions.   - Best regards.

Comment: @sircapsalot - Sure, the menu thing was clear but the interface was not.  Just because a user asks for certain technology doesn't mean that is the best or only way to solve a problem.  Granted by answer was simplistic  but could have been a jumping-off point, not an end-to-end solution.  Anyway, thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Well through my own digging, i was able to find this which is pretty much what I would want.

http://code.comunicatek.com/en/tekslider_a_touch_focused_slider.html

Figured I'd post it so if anyone else was looking for the same thing, they'd see it